# ¿Como buscar una propiedad de una colección referenciada por id en mongo?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, moongose

Tengo el siguiente modelo Doctor:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')
const paginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2')

const doctorSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: [true, 'name is required'] },
    img: { type: String, required: false, default: 'uploads/images/default.svg' },
    hospital: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Hospital', required: [true, 'hospital is required']},
    lastUserModifedIt: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }
},{
    timestamps: true
});

doctorSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {message: 'This {PATH} is required'})
doctorSchema.plugin(paginate)
module.exports = mongoose.model('Doctor', doctorSchema);
```

Y el modelo Hospital:

```
const moongose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = moongose.Schema
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')
const paginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2')


const hospitalSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, unique: true, required: [true, 'name is required']},
    img: {type: String, default: 'uploads/images/default.svg'},
    lastUserModifedIt: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
},{
    timestamps: true
})

hospitalSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {message: 'This {PATH} is required'})
hospitalSchema.plugin(paginate)
module.exports = moongose.model('Hospital', hospitalSchema)
```

Y quiero realizar una búsqueda en el modelo Doctor, pero a la vez buscar en el modelo Hospital el campo 'name':

```
let data = [];

//term viene de una petición
let regexname = new RegExp(term, 'i')

const paginateDoctor = await Doctor.paginate({$or: [{
                         name:regexname}, {hospital: regexname}]},{
                         limit: limit,
                         page: page, 
                         populate: ({ 
                             path: 'lastUserModifedIt', 
                             select: '_id name email role img'},
                             {
                             path: 'hospital'
                             })})

        data = {
                doctors: paginateDoctor.docs,
                total: paginateDoctor.totalDocs,
                totalPages: paginateDoctor.totalPages,
                inPage: paginateDoctor.page,
                limit: paginateDoctor.limit
               }


       res.json({
           ok: true,
           message: data
       })
```

El problema que tengo es que Hospital esta referenciado por Id y yo quiero buscar el name del hospital, que puedo hacer para acceder a las demás propiedades del Hospital?, espero que me haya explicado bien gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de consulta deseas realizar? porque en tu `query` tienes un operador `$or` y lo usas sobre dos campos del modelo `Doctor`. A dicha consulta le estás pasando una expresión regular, sin embargo el campo `name` es de tipo `String` y el campo `hospital` es de tipo `ObjectId`. A parte de esta situación, lo que me pregunto es qué tipo de búsqueda estás intentando, porque la entiendo como que deseas buscar por nombre de `doctor` o por nombre de `hospital`. Siendo ambas dos entidades diferentes. ¿Podrías aclarar este punto? Saludos

Comment: Solo quiero buscar por nombre de doctor o hospital, como ya dijiste. Lo de la expresión regular del hospital es para no dejarlo vació por que no se como buscar el hospital por nombre en vez de por id. También tengo entendió que puedo realizar la consulta al modelo de Hospitales, y buscarlo ahí por nombre, pero como hago después para enviarlo en un objeto solo?, edite el post y agregue la como se enviaría los datos al frontend